# Docker image build error using Eclipse in linux

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, docker, archlinux, docker-build

I am trying to build a Docker image for a Spring Boot microservice project. I got this error:

```
org.mandas.docker.thentexceptions.DockerException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.thent.ClientProtocolException
```

Dockerfile I'am trying to build :

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8082
ADD /target//Eureka/target/Eureka-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar Eureka_Server.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar",Eureka_Server.jar]
```

I have configured remote access with systemd unit file and verified it's state :

```
[kagha@archbios ~]$ sudo netstat -lntp | grep dockerd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2375          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6512/dockerd
```

I'am using OS Arch Linux with Kernel version 5.10.79-1-lts and Eclipse Version: 2021-09 (4.21.0)

I am the only one who encountered this problem as I am using linux my other team members only had to tick the Expose daemon to tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS using docker desktop settings and they didin't encounter any problem .
I wasn't able to do the same manually and I'am new to docker .

I will appreciate any help and provide more information if needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is Eclipse involved?

Comment: @nitind I'am using Eclipse Docker Tooling plugin to build the image from inside Eclipse.

Comment: here's some screenshots:

https://ibb.co/k0Ms8L0

https://ibb.co/68B1mMJ

Comment: What happens when you try to build from the command line directly?